# Prometheus client cleaning up counter prematurely?

Tags: go, prometheus

I am trying to write a program which exposes prometheus metrics.
It is a simple program, where I want to increment a counter for every time my "run" method is called on my struct.

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

type myStruct struct {
    errorCount prometheus.Counter
}

func (s myStruct) initialize() {
    s.errorCount = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "my_counter",
        Help: "sample prometheus counter",
    })
}

func (s myStruct) run() {
    s.errorCount.Add(1)
}

func main() {
    s := new(myStruct)
    s.initialize()

    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())

    go func() {
        for {
            s.run()
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Above code fails with a "Failed to continue - bad access" error, every time I try to increment the counter. i.e. at this line

```
s.errorCount.Inc()
```

I am unable to determine why the counter suddenly disappears from memory (if I'm understanding the error message correctly).
I am determine if i am missing something fundamental w.r.t. Go, or am I using the prometheus client library incorrectly.

Comment: Are you running the program with a debugger? There's [an issue](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/852) with `delve`, which could lead to your error. Is the behaviour different when you run it without a debugger?

Comment: @xarantolus - I was running it in VSCode using delve. I tried your suggestion and ran it from the command line using "go run" but i still get a runtime error ```$go run sample.go 
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0x13d3859]
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `initialise()` `s` is being passed by value which means that in `main()` `s.errorCount` is `nil`.

Just change the declaration of `initialise` (and `run`) to take a pointer.

```
func (s *myStruct) initialize() {
...
```

A few more suggestions you might like to try:

```
func init() {
    go func() {
        http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
    }()
}

type myStruct struct {
    errorCount prometheus.Counter
}

func NewMyStruct() *myStruct {
    return &myStruct {
        errorCount: prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts {
            Name: "my_counter",
            Help: "sample prometheus counter",
        }),
    }
}

func (s *myStruct) run() {
    s.errorCount.Add(1)
}

func main() {
    s := NewMyStruct()

    go func() {
     for {
         s.run()
         time.Sleep(time.Second)
     }
    }()

    // ... OR select{}
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AJR. I knew it had to be some small thing i was missing :)